# Remove JAutodoc Comments in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jautodoc

I have started to use JAutodoc in Eclipse. I'm able to create/update comments. But, is there any way to remove the created comments, instead of deleting them manually?

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for the same, but did not find any option from JAutodoc. Finally got the following work around in few clicks -

1) Popup the context menu on the file by right clicking

2) Then choose either one of the following from the context menu:

a) 'Local History' => 'Replace with Previous'

b) 'Replace With' => 'Previous from Local History'

c) 'Compare With' => 'Local History' => choose version by date => 'Copy All Non-Conflicting Changes from Right to Left'

Here is a screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression to find/replace ALL the comments on your project:

```
/\*{1,2}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\@\(\)\*\s/]*/
```

1. In eclipse open **Search** -> **File**
2. **Containing text** copy this -> `/\*{1,2}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\@\(\)\*\s/]*/`
3. **File name patterns** -> `*.java`
4. **Replace** (check Regular expression)
5. **Ok**

**CAREFULLY**! This operation, will remove ALL the comments on your project! **Not only from jAutodoc.**

Answer (score 0):

You can at least remove private method javadoc by modifying «Juan Carlos Contreras Vázquez» regex and by going into «In eclipse open Search -> File» and search with the following:

```
/\*{2}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\@\(\)\*\s/]*\*/\R  private
```

But again it removes every private methods javadoc.